# extracting data from seaborn kdeplot levels (2D) python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, unpack

Is it possible to get data from a kdeplot when its input is 2D?
I have the following:

```
import numpy as np    
from seaborn import kdeplot

lA = np.randon.normal(1,0.2,1000)
ld = np.randon.normal(1,0.2,1000)
kde = kdeplot(x=lA,y=ld)
```

If this was just 1D, I could get the information with:

```
lA = np.randon.normal(1,0.2,1000)
kde = kdeplot(lA)
line = kde.lines[0]
x, y = line.get_data()
```

but as a the input is 2D `(lA, ld)` , it returns an `<AxesSubplot:>` object and I don't know how to unpack its information since `kde.lines[0]` then returns `list index out of range`.
I need to compute the maximum and minimum in each of the plotted contour's axis (separately) as my dispersion for each variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the path drawn in the graph, in this case, from the LineCollection object.

```
import numpy as np    
from seaborn import kdeplot
import random
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

lA = np.random.normal(1,0.2,1000)
ld = np.random.normal(1,0.2,1000)
kde = kdeplot(x=lA,y=ld)

data = []
for i in kde.get_children():
    if i.__class__.__name__ == 'LineCollection':
        data.append(i.get_paths())

kde.get_children()
[<matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x28fb3ec2fd0>,
 <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x28fb3ed5320>,
 <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x28fb3ed55f8>,
 <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x28fb3ed58d0>,
 <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x28fb3ed5ba8>,
 <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x28fb3ed5e80>,
 <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x28fb3ee1198>,
 <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x28fb3ee1470>,
 <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x28fb3ee1748>,
 <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x28fb3ee1a20>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x28fb0cd3898>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x28fb0cd3978>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x28fb0cd3a58>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x28fb0cd3b38>,
 <matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x28fb0cd3828>,
 <matplotlib.axis.YAxis at 0x28fb0cd3eb8>,
 Text(0.5, 1.0, ''),
 Text(0.0, 1.0, ''),
 Text(1.0, 1.0, ''),
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x28fb3eb9630>]

data[0]
[Path(array([[1.0194036 , 0.43072548],
        [1.02780525, 0.42839334],
        [1.0362069 , 0.4265304 ],
        ...,
        [1.01100196, 0.43337965],
        [1.01752133, 0.43134949],
        [1.0194036 , 0.43072548]]), None)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the solution r-beginners, it does solve the problem. I just had some trouble accessing data[0] to get the 'vertices' values since it is a Path object and I am not familiar with those.
But following your answer I think it could be more straightforward (for my particular problem) to use this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from seaborn import kdeplot
from matplotlib import collections
import numpy as np

lA = np.random.normal(1, 0.2, 1000)
ld = np.random.normal(1, 0.2, 1000)
kde = kdeplot(x=lA, y=ld, levels=[0.3173]) # to get 1-sigma equivalent level

# Here I get the vertices information for each axis
p = kde.collections[0].get_paths()[0]
v = p.vertices
lx = [v[r][0] for r in range(len(v))]
ly = [v[r][1] for r in range(len(v))]

# Then I plot the horizontal limits of lx
plt.axvline(min(lx), c='r')
plt.axvline(max(lx), c='r')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to extract the points from a bivariate kdeplot, and export them all to excel. Here is my solution:

```
df = pd.read_excel("XXXX.xlsx",header=0)

c1 = df['X']
c2 = df['y']

g = sns.kdeplot(data=data, x=c1, y=c2, shade=False, fill=False)
ax = plt.gca() 

list=[]
i = -1
while i < 11:
    path_col1 = matplotlib.collections.AsteriskPolygonCollection.get_paths(ax.collections[i])
    list.append(path_col1)
    i = i+1
print(list)

extracted_ALL_paths = pd.DataFrame(list)
extracted_ALL_paths.to_csv("insert path here")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide a screen shot or other rendering to display the output of your solution? For example, see the other answer to the question.